# Issues with ListView here in C#

Tags: c#, linq

So I'm working on learning `LINQ` and was assigned to work with two `.txt` files and to join them.

So far I'm doing well, but I've reached a bit of an impasse with the display. I'm supposed to have the name display once and then the following cases that are closed have only the case information.

The issue I'm having is that the name keeps repeating after the dataset is listed in the `ListView`. I think there is something wrong with the `LINQ` statement or the way I'm going through the `foreach` loop. Here is the code for the main form below:

```
//Fills the lists by calling the methods from the DB classes
            techs = TechnicianDB.GetTechnicians();
            incidents = IncidentDB.GetIncidents();
            //Creates a variable to use in the LINQ statements
            var ClosedCases = from Incident in incidents
                              join Technician in techs
                              on Incident.TechID equals Technician.TechID
                              where Incident.DateClosed!= null
                              orderby Technician.Name, Incident.DateOpened descending
                              select new { Technician.Name, Incident.ProductCode, Incident.DateOpened, Incident.DateClosed, Incident.Title };
            //variables to hold the technician name, and the integer to increment the listview
            string techName = "";
            int i = 0;

            //foreach loop to pull the fields out of the lists and to display them in the required areas in the listview box
            foreach (var Incident in ClosedCases)
            {
                foreach (var Technician in ClosedCases)
                {
                    if (Technician.Name != techName)
                    {
                        lvClosedCases.Items.Add(Technician.Name);
                        techName = Technician.Name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lvClosedCases.Items.Add("");
                    }
                }

                lvClosedCases.Items[i].SubItems.Add(Incident.ProductCode);
                lvClosedCases.Items[i].SubItems.Add(Incident.DateOpened.ToString());
                lvClosedCases.Items[i].SubItems.Add(Incident.DateClosed.ToString());
                lvClosedCases.Items[i].SubItems.Add(Incident.Title);
                i++;
            }
```

And here is the result I get: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWKDr.png)

As can be seen by the bar on the right hand side, the list continues on for several more columns.

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

EDIT: Per request, here is what the results are supposed to look like:

[The example I was given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggtc3.png)

Comment: Providing an example, your expect output, and your actual output would clarify your question. Because no one has your raw data, it's hard to help.

Comment: As Louis mentioned, please provide an example. Difficult to imagine what you are expecting and what you are receiving.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your problem, but have you considered using ObjectListView control instead?  http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html  It takes some time to get used to, but makes things like this much easier to deal with.

Comment: Hi Matthew, welcome to StackOverflow.  I think what you're missing is the ability to step through your code and debug it.  If you did this, you'd see that the nested `foreach` statements are causing the problem.  I suggest you learn how to step through executing code in whatever IDE you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are iterating closed cases twice?

```
foreach (var Incident in ClosedCases)
 {
    foreach (var Technician in ClosedCases)
   {
   }
 }
```